# Error changing properties file in tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I got a strange problem in Tomcat using Eclipse. I've modified some properties in `weibo_config.properties` file, which configure the Weibo API. However, the modified attributes remain the earlier value.

**Expected result**
before modification: `key = OLD_KEY`
after modification: `key = NEW_KEY`

**Realty**
before modification: `key = OLD_KEY`
after modification : `key = OLD_KEY`

**What I've tried** :

- clean the tomcat server
- remove the web app in tomcat
- restart eclipse

But it didn't work. By the way, my collegue used **MyEclipse** as an IDE, it works after sychornizing my properties modification. So it was rather a configuration problem.

So what should I do in order to fix this problem ?

Comment: Where did you modify these values? In your project? And does this modified weibo_config.properties get deployed within the war?

Comment: If you modify the properties outside of eclipse, the least you should do is right-click on the file in eclipse and "refresh".
Also, even if you modify from inside eclipse, you probably have to "publish" the server (in the server view).

Comment: I've modified these values in my project in Eclipse. But I don't know how to check whether this properties file is deployed within the war... :( @UweAllner

Comment: I modified the properties within Eclipse. But as you said, I didn't refresh the project. And I didn't publish the server. (I thought the clean option includes the publish option). Whatever, it works at the end. Thanks @geert3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these values are modified outside of eclipse, press <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the project.

Then try:

- **Clean** the tomcat server
- **Publish** the tomcat server

Thanks [Uwe Allner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2621706/uwe-allner) and [geert3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201506/geert3). Edit my answer if it doesn't work for you.
For further info: [Eclipse: Difference between clean, build and publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656989/eclipse-difference-between-clean-build-and-publish)